# Force sampling Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can I force sampling with Google Analytics API v4? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

`samplingLevel - SMALL` didn't help

Our client sees the sampled data in the interface. They take `month` as period (f.e from 1 Feb to 28 Feb) and get some metric values like sessions. When we get this report from API there's no sampled values, all is fine (but in interface values sample). So, values don't match and client doesn't understand this. They want to see the values received through the API are the same as in the GA interface. So we need to get sampled data. But API returns non-sampled.

And my second question is: Google Analytics API v4 will down at July 2023? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en
Should we switch to GA4 as soon as possible?